# denseness of rational numbers in $Q$

Tags: calculus

Firstly, Let's consider the denseness of rational numbers in real numbers.

Between two arbitrary real numbers, there is at least one rational number. `And` we say that $Q$ is dense in $R$.

One equivalent definition: one arbitrary real number $a$, there must exist one rational number sequence which converges to $a$.

Secondly, consider the denseness of rational numbers itself.

Betwteen two arbitrary rational numbers, there is at least one rational number.

---

However, when I use the equivalent definition, that is: one arbitrary rational number $a$, there must exist one rational number sequence which converges to $a$.

Is this right? and how is it equivalent with the denseness of rational numbers in $Q$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is trivial as **any** set in a topological space is dense in itself...

If you insist in sequences, take

$$a_n=a\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a topological space and $S \subseteq X$, we say that $S$ is dense in $X$ if $\overline{S} = X$, where $\overline{S}$ is the closure of $S$ in $X$. If $X$ is a metric space like $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S$ is dense in $X$ if and only if every $x \in X$ is the limit of a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of elements of $S$ (*i.e.*, if and only if $x$ is a limit point of $S$). So to show that $S = \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $X = \mathbb{Q}$, you need to show that for each rational $q$, there is a rational sequence $\{q_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n = q$. So just take $\{q_n\}$ to be the constant sequence $q_n = q$ for all $n$.